# Optional ImageField (Django)

Tags: django, django-templates, django-models

I'm having a problem with an ImageField in one of my models. It is set to blank=True, null=True (it is optional.)

When I loop through a list of objects and use object.thumbnail.url, I get "Caught an exception while rendering: The 'thumbnail' attribute has no file associated with it."

This only happens if no thumbnail has been uploaded, obviously.

Does anyone have any ideas on the best way to deal with that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turned out it was as simple as:

```
{% if object.thumbnail %}
    <img src="{{ object.thumbnail.url }}" />
{% endif %}
```

Comment: weird. i thought template vars were supposed to fail silently.

Comment: Me too, that's what threw me!

Comment: This is weird , i was using it to get data for JSON, and me too hit the same error, whats the meaning of (blank=True,null=True) in models then?
I had to use conditional.
item.pic.url if item.pic else None